# Do I need to have another layer of security between my front-end app and my Firebase database?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, backend, firebase-security

I'm self taught, and been coding just for myself for personal projects, so never had an impression from anyone else.

I've been using Firebase since I've started coding (about a year and a half ago) and I pretty much execute all the actions from my front-end. In `React.js` for example I just have my actions file and do all the `set`, `update`, file uploads etc from there.

I've recently started learning `Node.js` and `MongoDB` and was surprised at how similar the two are, but that kind of confused me. Should I have used another "layer" of security between my front-end and my Firebase data base?

My intuition says that the Firestore rules are what covers that part, so no, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: when you use Firebase, the role of the traditional server is taken by:

- Security rules
- Your application code
- Cloud Functions

I'd typically consider this a prioritized list: first try to catch logic in security rules, then perform them in application code (and use security rules to ensure they still follow your business rules), and finally implement them in Cloud Functions if you can't capture it in rules and client-side code.